# how to replace NULL values with 0 when calculating the AVG in HIVE

Tags: hive

I'm calculating the AVG for a column in HIVE (using a Windowing function). The query looks like this

```
SELECT AVG(price) (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY mnth DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 12 FOLLOWING)
```

The `price` column has some NULL values and the `AVG` function do not consider them in the calculation. However I need want the NULL values to be dealt with as 0. I use `NVL` as follows

```
SELECT AVG(NVL(price)) (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY mnth DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 12 FOLLOWING)
```

However this doesn't work. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT AVG(NVL(price, 0))

You forgot about second parameter (default_value)